# Constraints in ebean java play framework not reflected in generated sql

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, playframework, ebean

I am using ebean ORM in my java based play framework and following is my model

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import com.avaje.ebean.annotation.CreatedTimestamp;
import com.avaje.ebean.annotation.UpdatedTimestamp;

import play.db.ebean.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

@Entity 
@Table(name = "coupons")
public class Coupon extends com.avaje.ebean.Model {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Constraints.MaxLength(80)
    @Constraints.MinLength(10)
    private String title;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Constraints.MaxLength(1000)
    @Constraints.MinLength(10)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @CreatedTimestamp
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    @UpdatedTimestamp
    private Date updatedAt;

    @Column(name = "valid_from")
    private Date validFrom = new Date();

    @Column(name = "valid_to")
    private Date validTo = new Date((long)2147483647*1000);


}
```

Generated sql file is

```
create table coupons (
  id                            bigserial not null,
  title                         varchar(255),
  description                   varchar(255),
  valid_from                    timestamp,
  valid_to                      timestamp,
  created_at                    timestamp not null,
  updated_at                    timestamp not null,
  constraint pk_coupons primary key (id)
);

drop table if exists coupons cascade;
```

Does ebean convert the constraints into sql file? How do I make sure my constraints are reflected in sql file also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ebean does not read any of the Play constraint annotations.

```
@Constraints.Required
@Constraints.MaxLength(80)
```

So the `Required` and `MaxLength` are not read and hence don't effect the generated DDL.

Ebean reads the JPA annotations and the `javax.validation.constraints` annotations `@NotNull` and `@Size`.  For example, you could use:

```
@NotNull
@Size(max = 80)
```

Comment: where did you find this information? I didnt find it in documentation.

Comment: I am the main committer to Ebean. I wrote the Ebean code that reads those annotations.

Comment: how do I set default values in ebean so that setting default values also shows up in sql file?

Comment: `@Size` is a Bean Validation annotation, not a JPA annotation.
As far as I can tell, there is no annotation for ebean constraint that can be used to ensure a minimum string length, or even an to ensure that the string is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Ebean uses only [JPA Annotations](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/toplink-jpa-annotations-096251.html).

You can check out the docs for the [@Column](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/ias/toplink-jpa-annotations-096251.html#Column) annotation, which has options such as

```
@Column(nullable = false)
```

However, there are no options for minimum or maximum string length, or to ensure that the string is not empty.